# Proving Uniform Continuity of Fourier transform (Related to measure theory)

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, fourier-transform, uniform-continuity

Let $\mu$ be a finite measure on $(\mathbf{R},\mathcal{B})$. Define $\hat\mu(t)=\int{e^{-itx} d\mu(x)} , t\in \mathbf{R}$. Show that the function $\hat\mu$ is uniformly continuous on $\mathbf{R}$. $\hat\mu$ is called fourier transform of $\mu$.

I think I should use Bounded Convergence Theorem. That should hold for Complex valued functions as well. So, we get if $t_n\rightarrow t$ as $n\rightarrow \infty, \int|e^{-it_n x}-e^{-itx}|d\mu(x)\rightarrow 0 $ as $n\rightarrow \infty$ as $| e^{-it_n x}|\leq 1$. Does this imply uniform continuity? I can't see that.

Comment: *Hint.* For $s, t \in \mathbb{R}$, $|\hat{\mu}(s) - \hat{\mu}(t)| \leq \int |1-e^{i(s-t)x}| \, \mu(dx)$.

Comment: thanks for the help. I see your result. but how does it help? some clarification please. actually i am looking for an $\epsilon,\delta$ argument

Comment: By the dominated convergence theorem, $$ \lim_{h\to 0} \int \left| 1 - e^{ihx} \right| \, \mu(dx) = 0. $$ So, for each $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $$ |h| < \delta \quad \Rightarrow \quad \int \left| 1 - e^{ihx} \right| \, \mu(dx) < \epsilon. $$ Now try to argue that the definition of uniform continuity for $\hat{\mu}$ is satisfied with this very choice of $\delta$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I see it now.